# header(Location:) via AJAX not redirecting

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, redirect, http-headers

First off, let me say that I know this does not seem like an uncommon issue.  I do not intend to clutter these forums with questions that have already been answered, but, I have worked through probably about 3 dozen threads with similar issues and have been unable to reach a solution.

The short description of my issue is this: I am trying to redirect after submitting a form using php's header(location:) function, and it's not redirecting.  It is a little bit complicated because the form is submitted via AJAX.  The steps my code goes through are as follows:

User submits form > form data sent via AJAX > form processing page validates data > if valid, form processing page inserts data into database > if submission is successful, form processing page adds redirect URL to $_SESSION > form processing page returns a 'redirect' variable > javascript/AJAX checks for redirect variable, and refreshes page if found > page header checks $_SESSION for redirect URL, and if found, sets appropriate headers and exits.

I guess the first thing I want to ask is, is this the right way of going about this? It seems to me that there should be a simpler way of doing this. It's obviously much simpler to pass the redirect URL to the javascript and do a window.location redirect, but I read that it's much better/more secure to handle that on the server side, so I'm trying to do that.

Assuming I'm going about this in the right direction, what could be going wrong here? I've checked for leading and trailing whitespace, BOM characters, I've even tried output buffering and I still have the same issue.

What happens on form submission is, the page refreshes, but it returns to the original form page rather than the redirect url.  I have turned on the most detailed error reporting and get no errors at all.

One thing that may or may not be of interest, I have an error_log function set up to log all headers to a file right after I set the Location: header.  When I redirect outside of AJAX (which works), the accept: header is set to html, but when I try to do it via AJAX, the accept header is set to JSON.  Could that cause a problem?

Thank you so much for taking the time, and again, apologies if this is a dumb question.  I have used this forum for years and have never once had to post a question on it because it has always solved my problems until now.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: `window.location` is just as good as sending the location in the header. In either way you can't control what the client actually does. You can't change the original's page location via PHP only when using ajax. Go with JS or don't use ajax.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is too generous to include in your code not only HTML code, but also JavaScript code. I'll explain one thing. When you send data by ajax, it is often difficult return Boolean data (whether true or false, depending on the conditions we work side server with php in some file established in our direction ajax) to give a final answer.

On the other hand, returning to the generosity of PHP, always when we try to validate data server-side and through ajax, we can manipulate the section where work freely to show some response message, a redirect to somewhere on your page or create a session. Anyway, whatever.

What I mean is that in your controller section where you will work with AJAX, you can set different conditions. That is, if the user data are correct, then you could send to call a script from Javascript to redirect him with a location.reload (); and also assign a session automatically. If the user does not have the correct data, then what we should do is return a warning message or alert to the exit AJAX, usually it goes after a:

```
function (response) {
$ ('.answer').html(response);
}
```

Note that it is not necessary require, for example, a $ ('.answer').html(response); to return an answer, because ajax only sends data to the server and if there is a reply message well, and if not well. Many times what I do, is to send messages via console, although it is often convenient to do so, because as often work with several conditions and that depends on the result of our request, we will be forced to show some response in some element within our code.

What I advise you is that you work javascript in PHP, and hence redirect to other pages, assign sessions or simply return a message. Remember that an ajax request is not only asynchronous, but repetitive and can send it to call as often as you need. The fact that you sent your ajax call php file and you have returned an answer, does not mean you can go back to work with it once you finish your ajax request.

It is the right way to do what you want, it is often easier to manipulate our server-side code that client side. Greetings.